# Generic type but exclude array types

Tags: typescript

If I have a function that takes any type and returns it, how can I ensure the function won't accept an array type? I want to accept all types except arrays.

```
function someFunc<T>(arg: T): T { return arg; }
```

This should be valid:

```
someFunc('string');
```

But this should fail:

```
someFunc(['string', 'string2']);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```js
function someFunc<T>(arg: Exclude<T, any[]>): T { return arg; }

someFunc('string'); // OK

// Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
// ^ Error appears on the whole array
someFunc<any[]>([]);

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
// ^ Error appears on each array element
someFunc<any[]>(['string', 'string2']);

// Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
// ^ Error appears on the whole array
someFunc([]);

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
// ^ Error appears on each array element
someFunc(['string', 'string2']);

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
// ^ Error appears on each array element
someFunc<string[]>(['string', 'string2']);
```

The errors it produces are a little bit unexpected, but they're there.

Comment: This seems to be excluding `any[]` specifically, meaning this will pass the compiler successfully: `someFunc<string[]>(['a', 'b'])` and needs to have `any[]` specifically passed as the generic arg for it to fail. Is it possible to do this without using `any` or `unknown`?

I had initially thought this would work: `Exclude<T, T[]>` but it does not

Comment: I'll update my answer with more examples, but it also works for other (interfered) types.

Answer (score 0):

#### Best solution: use Exclude

Kelvin's answer seems to be the best fit for the question. I proposed the following solution before I saw his response:

#### Solution 1: Return never

In line with the other answer already given, return never if the given type is an array. This will not give a compiler error when calling the function, but the user cannot do anything with the returned value.

```
function someFunc<T>(arg: T): T extends any[] ? never : T {
  return arg as any; // need cast to satisfy compiler
}

const a = someFunc("");
// type of a: string

const b = someFunc([1]);
// no compiler error, but type of b: never
```

#### Solution 2: Exclude random method only available on arrays

You can take some random method that is only available on the type you want to exclude. Here I take the `push` method:

```
function someFunc<T>(arg: T & { push?: never }): T {
  return arg;
}

someFunc(""); // no problem
someFunc([1]); // compiler error
```

Comment: Can you explain why you don't consider the other answer to be "a 'clean' way"? Is that not the intended use of 'Exclude'?

Comment: You're right, Exclude seems to be the best fit for the problem. Somehow I tried it before and the compiler did not behave as requested, but I now verified that it does. I updated my answer to point to the other solution.